# Flutter Firebase Firestore, Read Cache first, then Server

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, future, riverpod

I try to read the cache first and then from the server.
This is not working.

```
class ProgramService extends AsyncNotifier<List<Program>> {
  Future<List<Program>> _getPrograms() async {
    final _fireStoreRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('program');
    var snapshot =
        await _fireStoreRef.get(const GetOptions(source: Source.cache));
    if (snapshot.docs.isEmpty) {
      snapshot =
          await _fireStoreRef.get(const GetOptions(source: Source.server));
    }
    print(snapshot.metadata.isFromCache ? 'from cache' : 'from server');

    final value =
        snapshot.docs.map((docs) => Program.fromJson(docs.data())).toList();
    return value;
  }

  @override
  Future<List<Program>> build() async {
    return _getPrograms();
  }
}

final asyncProgramProvider =
    AsyncNotifierProvider<ProgramService, List<Program>>(() {
  return ProgramService();
});
```

Does anyone have a working example.

I read the provider correctly

Comment: "This is not working" is hard to help with. What did you expect this code to output, and what does it output instead? I typically helps if you `print` some value that shows exactly what is different from what you expect, and then include *that* updated code and its output in your question.

Comment: I want data to be searched for in the cache only. If no data is available, the data should be queried from the server. If there is no Data available while the App is starting then, the data is read over and over again from the server. If the cache is empty, then it should fallback to the server, followed by the cache.